# How do I get windows to have borders/titlebars after upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, gnome-classic, titlebar, release-upgrade, window-decoration

I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04.  Upgrade seemed to have no problems, but when I open a window it has no border or title·bar.

I am using Gnome classic.

Oddly, Google chrome does have Minimize, Full-size & Close boxes.

Under gnome classics (no effects) the window title·bar is there.

Under Gnome I get a title·bar but without Minimize or Maximize, only Close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is a known bug since 4/4/12.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/973559

If this is happening to you, go to the bug and mark it as affecting you.

---

I fixed this problem (by stumbling around).

Since I have other, older distributions working with Compiz, I opened ccsm from one of them and compared them to the 12.04 upgrade.

Strangely, after enabling Windows decorations, move, and re·size the problems stated is this question were solved.

By setting others from the older ccsm, I got a rotating cube.

Alas, there are no more 3D windows

**UPDATE**: 3D windows are available for **Gnome Classic**. The Compiz PluginsExtra is required.  Synaptic is required to install Compiz PluginsExtra, it is not available in Ubuntu Software Center. And they work very nicely!

[image]

Screen shots of the older (10.10), working ccsm window can be seen at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/994893

**UPDATE** Although not mentioned in release notes, cube and 3D windows are not a part of Ubuntu.  Compiz settings may changed when logging out of Gnome Classic and into Unity, then back.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used GNOME Classic. I would assume you can find it under PREFERENCES >>> LOOK AND FEEL or CUSTOMIZE LOOK AND FEEL. Search around under PREFERENCES you will find somethign there to change the THEME of your GDM.

Comment: Under System Settings… Appearance… I can change "Theme" and background.  My choices are Ambiance (default), Adwaita, High Contrast, High Contrast and High Contrast Inverse.  Adwaita and Ambiance when selected, do not provide title·bar or borders.